# How can i add a video as a HUD element in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to add a video that shows up when i call it but not a typical (stretch-to-bounds) view
similar to the ProgressHud view that loads in the middle and darkens the background. how can I load a video say from LBYoutubeController or natively? 
Thanks!

edit: ideally the video box will take up 60-70 % of the screen but again will be centered and overshadowing the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `MPMoviePlayerController`. You can set the `controlStyle` to `MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded` and this will give you a player with no controls. Set the `scalingMode` to `MPMovieScalingModeFill` to make the video conform to the frame you set for it regardless of the video's natural layout. Just add the movie player's `view` to your view hierarchy and you're good to go.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
[myView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

To add a dimming view behind this:

```
UIView *back = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:myView.bounds];
back.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;
back.alpha = 0.7;
[myView insertSubview:back belowSubview:myView];
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks, will this also add the HUD effect by where the background items are transparent as the view, or do i have to additionally like lower the opacity in the call of this program

Comment: @GurinderSingh I edited my original answer to include adding a background view. Please "accept" my answer! Thanks!